# How to write a visual studio compilable code to create a c++ websocket server using WebSocketpp library

Tags: visual-c++

The problem is that I need a working code for a websocket server which continuouslu listens to a port until specified otherwise and then read messages recieved from its clients and can delete certain websockets.

But the documentation is not clear and I need and a standard way of creating a c++ implementation of a websocket in visual studio but have no idea how

Please tell me how to proceed with such an implementation

I have already tried the following code given here:
https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/tutorials/utility_server/step2.cpp

But even though the code compiles the server listening to the port specifed closes instantaneously. I am not sure if it correct to just use a simple while loop here ,and other than that there is no mention of how to handle or check the sockets that are connected with the server.

```cpp
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

#include <functional>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

class utility_server {
public:
    utility_server() {
         // Set logging settings
        m_endpoint.set_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);
        m_endpoint.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all ^ websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);

        // Initialize Asio
        m_endpoint.init_asio();

        // Set the default message handler to the echo handler
        m_endpoint.set_message_handler(std::bind(
            &utility_server::echo_handler, this,
            std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2
        ));
    }

    void echo_handler(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg) {
        // write a new message
        m_endpoint.send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode());
    }

    void run() {
        // Listen on port 9002
        m_endpoint.listen(9002);

        // Queues a connection accept operation
        m_endpoint.start_accept();

        // Start the Asio io_service run loop
        m_endpoint.run();
    }
private:
    server m_endpoint;
};

int main() {
    utility_server s;
    s.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for VSCode to compile the project:

1 - I used C/C++ Project Generator 
2 - Put your websocketpp repository inside your include repository
3 - modify your "Makefile" as follows :

```
BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

CC  := g++
CPPFLAGS    := -Wall -fexceptions -g -I$(INCLUDE)


LINKER_OPT := -lpthread
LINK_LIB := /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so

EXECUTABLE  := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)

LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)


LISTINCLUDES := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))

CLIBS       := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))

SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))
OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -$(RM) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    -$(RM) $(OBJECTS)


run: all
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(info ************  Test my var ************)
$(info  $$BIN is [${BIN}])
$(info $$EXECUTABLE is [${EXECUTABLE}])
$(info $$OBJECTS is [${OBJECTS}])
$(info  $$CC is [${CC}])
$(info  $$CFLAGS is [${CFLAGS}])
$(info  $$HPPINCLUDES is [${LISTINCLUDES}])
$(info  $$CLIBS is [${CLIBS}])

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CLIBS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES) $(LINKER_OPT) $(LINK_LIB)
```

tool chain should looks like:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iinclude -c "/home/bc/Bureau/CODEBLOCK Projet C-C++/Websocket_test/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/Websocket_test obj/Debug/main.o  -lpthread  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
```